# JPA + Hibernate: How to define a constraint having ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I am just wondering if there's such a way that I can have build my MySQL table as

```sql
ALTER TABLE `USERINFO`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`USERID`) REFERENCES `USERACCOUNT` (`USERID`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

However, I only got this in my DDL when hibernate ++ jpa starts to build my table having "`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />`"

```sql
ALTER TABLE `USERINFO` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`USERID`) REFERENCES `USERACCOUNT` (`USERID`);
```

In my classes, I have these annotation setup,

```java
// UserAcc.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERACC")
public class UserAcc implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5527566248002296042L;

@Id
@Column(name = "USERID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer userId;


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userAcc")
private UserInfo userInfo;
....


public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
    return userInfo;
}
public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
    this.userInfo = userInfo;
}
...
```

and,

```java
// UserInfo.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERINFO")
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5924361831551833717L;

@Id
@Column(name = "USERINFO_ID", nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer userInfoId;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="USERID", nullable=false)
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER_ID")
private UserAcc userAcc;


public Integer getUserInfoId() {
    return userInfoId;
}

public void setUserInfoId(Integer userInfoId) {
    this.userInfoId = userInfoId;
}
...
```

Note that, UserAccount table is the parent/main table here while UserInfo is an extended table normalize to another entity. Any answers would be greatly appreciated. I'm just curious how it's done as I love to work also in MySQL. I am just really used to deleting a record from the parent table (USERACOUNT) which would would also allow me to cascade a delete thru child records dependent on the specific record from a parent/primary table.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem using jpa? I'm having the same problem and I don't want to use a bidirectional relation, creating lazy fetching on the parent.

Answer (score 16):

JPA does offer possibility to [cascade](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) operations (merge, persist, refresh, remove) to associated entities. Logic is in JPA and does not utilize database cascades.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

There is no JPA standard compliant way to do cascades with database cascades. If such a cascades are preferred, we have to fall back to Hibernate specific construct: [@OnDelete](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/). It works with `@OneToMany` at least, but there used to be some problems in the past with `@OneToOne` and `@OnDelete`.

```
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
```

Be aware that adding this annotation to an existing constraint will not update it. You may have to manually drop it first to properly update the schema.

Comment: Thanks Mikko. I tried including OnDelete with JPA annotations, it didn't work indeed. I have a question, when you wanted to manipulate your database and wanted to add ON DELETE CASCADE, particularly MySQL, how do you handle it?

Answer (score 11):

There is no clean cut means to do this in JPA. The following will get you what you want...
You can use `CascadeType.DELETE`, however this annotation only applies to the objects in the `EntityManager`, not the database. You want to be sure that `ON DELETE CASCADE` is added to the database constraint. To verify, you can configure JPA to generate a ddl file. Take a look at the `ddl` file, you'll notice that `ON DELETE CASCADE` is not part of the constraint. Add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to actual SQL in the `ddl` file, then update your database schema from the ddl. This will fix your problem .

This [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) shows how to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on for `CONSTRAINT` in MySQL. You do this on the constraint. You can also do it in a `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statement. It's likely that JPA creates the constraint in an `ALTER TABLE` statement. Simply add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to that statement.

Note that some JPA implementors do provide a means for this functionality.

Lastly, Hibernate does supply this functionality using the `OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` annotation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Hibernate annotation `org.hibernate.annotations@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` on `UserAcc.userInfo`:

```
public class UserAcc implements Serializable {

...

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userAcc")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private UserInfo userInfo;

...
```

this will generate DDL `ON DELETE CASCADE` on foreign key in `UserInfo`  table.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the constraint manually by using @JoinColumn(`foreignKey = @ForeignKey(...)`) as follows:-

```
// UserInfo.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERINFO")
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5924361831551833717L;

@Id
@Column(name = "USERINFO_ID", nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer userInfoId;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(
        name="USERID", 
        nullable=false,
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                name="FK_USER_ID",
                foreignKeyDefinition = "FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES USERACCOUNT(USERID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE"
        )
)
private UserAcc userAcc;


public Integer getUserInfoId() {
    return userInfoId;
}

public void setUserInfoId(Integer userInfoId) {
    this.userInfoId = userInfoId;
}
...
```

This will add the constraint during generating DDL.

After the generation process is completed, you can check the DDL of `USERINFO` table and you will find that the constraint has been added with the cascading actions as shown below:-

```
create table USERINFO(
    ....,
    ....,
    ....,
    ....,
    constraint FK_USER_ID foreign key (USERID) references USERACCOUNT(USERID) on update cascade on delete cascade
);
```

Answer (score 0):

please config your mySql alter the table forgein key `on update noaction` an `on delete no action`
and apply

```
 @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();
```