# Cannot delete parent and child

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have two entities using Spring and Hibernate

Entity A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
    private B b;
```

Here i have a one to one relationship with Entity B, the owner of the relationship is Entity A.

Entity B:

```
@Entity
public class B{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_ID")
    private A a;
```

Saving the entities gives no problem. Entity B gets the ID of entity A in the Database.
But when i delete Entity A, I also want to delete Entity B that belongs to A.

When I delete i get the error:

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I think my declarations in my entities are correct. What is the problem here?

### Edit

When I inspect the table of Entity B and specifically the Foreign key to Entity A it says Restricted on Update en on Delete

Comment: You need the define CASCADE ON DELETE...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA + Hibernate: How to define a constraint having ON DELETE CASCADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875793/jpa-hibernate-how-to-define-a-constraint-having-on-delete-cascade)

Comment: @RaymondNijland That doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

set orphanRemoval property to true in class A

like this: `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)`

Comment: Do you have remove method for child entity in parent class ?

Comment: Yes i have put orphanRemoval = true in Entity A. And Entity A is the parent if i understand you correctly.

Comment: you should have add and remove entity method in class A like this :
 
    public void removeB() {
        if (b!= null) {
           b.setA(null);
        }
        this.b= null;
    }