# JPA2.0 & Hibernate: Removing Child table rows with Parent entity merge (On removing entries from parent's child entity set)

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA2.O with Hibernate. I have one to many relationship between User and Address and I have below configuration with this relationship:

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
```

For example I have below entries in database tables:

**User Table**

```
Column: UserID | UserName
row1:    User1 | UserName
```

**Address Table**

```
Column: AddressId| UserID | Address    

row1:   Address1 | User1  | Actual Address

row2:   Address2 | User1  | Actual Address
```

I can fetch User entity using find by userId:

```
User user = entityManager.find(User.class, userId);
```

And also can fetch Answers using user.getAddresses(). Code for getAddressess() is like below:

```
public class User{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
       return this.addresses;
    }
}
```

Now what I am trying to do, I am fetching the set of addresses and removing one entry. Let say I fetched addressess set first time I have address 1 and 2. I removed address 2 entity from set of addresses. Now User entity is pointing to the Set which is having only 1 entry that is for Address1.

Now If I merge user entity using below method, I think, row for address 2 should be deleted from address table. But it is not happening. Am I missing any thing or it is not a way to do it. Please suggest.

```
entityManager.merge(user);
```

Comment: 1) suggest to change to @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
2) please provide more code for frist and second cases

Comment: Thanks Michail. This worked for me. I also got a very nice description from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329577/jpa-2-0-orphanremoval-true-vs-on-delete-cascade.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add more detail as I got this working.

I added **orphanRemoval = true** with **@OneToMany** relationship:

```
public class User{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
       return this.addresses;
    }
}
```

After changing my code I re-tested it and got below error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:
```

[This link](http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/188/hibernateexception-a-collection-with-cascade-all-delete-orphan-was-no-longer-referenced-by-the-owning-entity-instance/) helped me to solve above problem:

Now I can delete the child entities from database, if those are disconnected(removed) from defined collection in parent entity.

Comment: link provided is broken

Comment: Thanks a lot.     orphanRemoval = true, solved my issue. I also used 'fetch = FetchType.EAGER'. I saw in other questions programmers have advised remove 'fetch = FetchType.EAGER'. But for me it worked. If I remove 'fetch = FetchType.EAGER' then my update fails.  I configured my parent entity as this: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objWatchList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)

Comment: Good to hear that it worked for you. Enjoy coding !!