# Hibernate can not correctly operates on multiple bags

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

I have a model which has 2 oneToMany relation to another 2 model. When i remove 1 record from first bag and save the object, hibernate removes 1 record from 1st bag which is ok but it also removes the record which has same index as the record in first bag from 2nd bag. I can not figure it out how to fix it.

Here is my models

Owner:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class Owner extends Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
 private int id;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @OrderColumn(name = "position")
 private List<Dog> dogs;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @OrderColumn(name = "position")
 private List<Cat> cats;

 public Long getId() {
    this.id;     
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 public Dog getDogs() {
    return this.dogs;
 }

 public void setDogs(List<Dog> dogs) {
    this.dogs = dogs;
 }

 public void addDog(Dog dog) {
    dog.owner = this;
    this.dogs.add(dog);
 }

 public void removeDog(Dog dog) {
    this.dogs.remove(dog);
 }

  public Dog getCats() {
    return this.cats;
 }

 public void setCats(List<Cat> cats) {
    this.cats = cats;
 }

 public void addCat(Cat cat) {
    Cat.owner = this;
    this.cats.add(cat);
 }

 public void removeCat(Cat cat) {
    this.cats.remove(cat);
 }
}
```

Dog:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class Dog extends Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
 private int id;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
 private Owner owner;

 @Column(name = "position")
 private int position;

 public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 public int getPosition() {
    return this.position;
 }

 public void setPosition(int index) {
    this.position = index;
 }

 public Owner getOwner() {
    return this.owner;
 }

 public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
 }
}
```

Cat:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_c")
public class Cat extends Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
 private int id;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
 private Owner owner;

 @Column(name = "position")
 private int position;

 public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 public int getPosition() {
    return this.position;
 }

 public void setPosition(int index) {
    this.position = index;
 }

 public Owner getOwner() {
    return this.owner;
 }

 public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
 }
}
```

Let say we had an owner which has 2 cats and 2 dogs.

when i do that:

```
Cat cat2Remove = owner.getCats().get(1);
owner.removeCat(cat2Remove);
session.save(owner);
```

Hibernate removes 2nd cat from table_b as i intend but it also removes 2nd dog from table_c and i wonder how can i prevent this in a proper way?

Comment: What do you mean with *also removes*? Is the record of dog also deleted from database or is it just retrieving/fetching the same amount of dogs that cats for the related collections? Please check this. I think you are suffering problems with fetching behavior due to `Owner` has two eager and indexed collection.

Comment: I've no problems with fetching. With @OrderColumn annotation hibernate handles eager fetching multiple bags. However, the record of dog also deleted from database.

Comment: In that case try to do `cat2remove.serOwner(null)` instead of `owner.removeCat(cat2Remove)`. This will respect JPA specification clause that says we should care about setting the owner side of bidirectional association, maybe hibernate works better this way

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` so you have to remove  `CascadeType.ALL` to understand the effect of cascade see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/) link.

if you want only to cascade on save-update use `cascade="save-update"`
i don't know if you need `orphanRemoval = true` in your case or not but look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329577/jpa-2-0-orphanremoval-true-vs-on-delete-cascade) answers to see if you need it in your business or not.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to generate a proper equals and hashCode pair to both of your entities.** Right now they have the exact same set of variables (id, owner, position) and likely being treated as "equals", hence they are being removed. If you write a proper equals check which also checks the object type (Eclipse can generate this for you under "Source" generate equals/hashcode menu) your problem should disappear instantly.

Comment: I am already checking object type in equals method but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, I think the underlying problem is how fetching strategy works for the case with two eager ordered collections. So to earn time I suggest you to try adding the follow Hibernate's annotation to both collection:

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
```

It tells to Hibernate that the collection's elements should be retrieved executing a separated select query from the one that retrieve the `Owner` instance information. It means without doing a join statement.