# JPA: 'CascadeType.REMOVE' or 'orphanRemoval = true', which use in a n:n relation that generate new table/class with EmbeddeId class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, cascade

I am developing an REST API to a pizzeria store. And here i'm trying to delete a Flavor and all data related to it. Further explained below:

Classes:

- `Flavor` have at least one `Filling`, each one taking a position on it.

  - i.e: Souce (at pos. 1), mozzarela (at pos. 2) tomato (at pos. 3)
- `Flavor`s must have a price to each `Size`

With that in mind, we can conclude that exist two many-to-many relationships:

- `Flavor` to many `Filling`
- `Flavor` to many `Size`

[Class diagram of actual implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVD1f.png)

The requirement is to: delete a `Flavor`, and automatically delete all the `FillingPositionFlavor` and `FlavorPriceSize`.

But,I'm confused on use of `CascadeType.REMOVE` and `orphanRemoval = true`:

When I use Cascade and OrphanRemoval on Flavor.sizePrices, get a HibernateException when trying to edit a Flavor, exclusion works fine:
`A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.pkg.Flavor.sizePrices`

When I use Cascade on Flavor.sizePrices, get a PSQLException when excluding a Flavor, editing works fine:
`ERROR: update or delete on table "tb_flavor" violates foreign key constraint "fk9orw0yhtc0e06ka84dbcd2c82" on table "tb_flavor_size_price"`

I'm doing unit testing of services in Spring Boot to test all the CRUD operations.

Below is the actual code, I hid properties like id and others to facilitate the read.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_flavor")
class Flavor {

   @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE},orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<FlavorPositionFilling> flavors = new HashSet<FlavorPositionFilling>();

   @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE},orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<FlavorPriceSize> priceSizes;

   // other properties and methods
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_flavor_price_size")
class FlavorPriceSize {

   @EmbeddedId
   private FlavorPriceSizeEmbeddeId id;
   private float price;

   // other properties and methods
}

@Embeddable
class FlavorPriceSizeEmbeddeId implements Serializable {
   @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
   @JoinColumn(name = "ID_FLAVOR_FK", referencedColumnName = "id_flavor")
   private Flavor flavor;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
   @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SIZE_FK", referencedColumnName = "id_size")
   private Size size;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_flabor_position_filling")
class FlaborPositionFilling {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FlaborPositionFillingEmbeddedId id;
    private Integer position;
}

@Embeddable
class FlaborPositionFillingEmbeddedId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_FLAVOR_FK", referencedColumnName="id_flavor")
    private Flavor sabor;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_FILLING_FK", referencedColumnName="id_filling")
    private Filling filling;
}
```

I've read a lot about both, but still not understand the right use of each and their effect on operations. Can anyone explain it to me? Show videos, images, code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you have a parent -> child relationship.

If you set **CacadeType.REMOVE** on the relationship every EntityManager.remove call on the parent will also remove the children.

**orphanRemoval = true** is used to delete orphan children.

So if remove a child from the parent reference or collection and save the parent the child will be deleted because its no longer attached to the parent.

Comment: So, if I have an **unidirectional** relationship: 
`entity (A) references (B)`, 
CascadeType.REMOVE will: when remove (A), remove (B) too.
 
If I have a **bidirectional** relationship: 
`entity (A) references (B)`, `entity (B) references (A)`, 
CascadeType.REMOVE will: when remove (A), remove (B) too, **but**, (B) has a reference to (A), which no more exist (A becomes _orphan_). So, `orphanRemoval = true` will remove the orphan (B) that references a nonexistent (A).

Is that right?

Comment: The first part is correct the second not. For the second if you remove the reference from B to A B will be removed because A no longer references B

Comment: I was looking for my db, and discovered that ORM was creating a new table for the many-to-many relationship even with the class I've created to it (don't know if it was the erro's author). So, I found articles about `mappedBy`, and resolved the new table's problem. Than, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4329723/11313634) answer that helped me to understand the `Cascade` and the `orphan`.