# Why to add orphanRemoval = true when CascadeAll

Tags: jpa

I updated my entity which has a oneToMany relationship expressed as a Set .

So I am using cascade = CascadeType.ALL . So when I added something to the set and updated my entity everything was fine.

But when I removed a child from SET and then updated it it was not removed from the cild table. It was stil in the database.

So I used orphanRemoval = true and yes it also was removed from the child table. Why when already using cascade = CascadeType.ALL which should include CascadeType.Remove I still have to say orphanRemoval = true ?

Comment: CascadeType.Remove means that the related entities are deleted when the owning entity is deleted

Comment: orphanRemoval = true means that related entity is deleted when set is not contain it and owning entity is saved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA 2.0 orphanRemoval=true VS on delete Cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329577/jpa-2-0-orphanremoval-true-vs-on-delete-cascade)

Comment: does Cascade.All include all the other CASCADEs like merge,remove,request ?

Comment: @Flo19 Yes, cascade type all is shorthand for all of the cascade operations.

Comment: is Cascade.Persist same as orphanRemoval = true ?

Comment: @Flo19 No, CascadeTypes has nothing to do with orphanRemoval. Here is explanation of Cascade types meaning https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-cascadetype-persist-example/

Comment: what does CascadeType.PERSIST mean ? if I do not use this, related entities would not be saved ??

Comment: @Flo19 CascadeType.PERSIST means that related entity is saved when the owning entity is saved

Comment: yeah but it seems only it adds but does not remove old stuff, that's why I needed orphanRemoval = true