# OrphanRemoval in hibernate not working when multilevel joining relations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a table structure with multi level joined relations like Parent have a one to many relationship with Child and Child have one to many relationship with ChildL2. I set `orphanRemoval` property true for all oneToMany joining.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    //other columns, getters & setters

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "RefId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Child> child;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

    //other columns, getters & setters

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "RefId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<ChildL2> childL2;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "childl2")
public class ChildL2 {

    //other columns , getters & setters
}
```

But when I try to delete 'parent' with following code, the corresonding rows of 'child' are removed successfully. But related 'childl2' rows are still remaining.

```java
Parent tempObj = new Parent();
tempObj.setId(36790);
session.delete(tempObj);
```

**Q:1** I need to know whether hibernate orphanRemoval property capable of dealing with multi level oneToMany joined relations?

**Q2** When I try to load by id using `CriteriaQuery.list()` , It consumes lot of time. I need to know whether any method to optimize it without change to FetchType.Lazy?

```java
Criteria queryCriteria = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
queryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Id", 36795));
List<Parent> dataList = queryCriteria.list();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your tempObj is not managed by a hibernate session..
Q1 - yes it does.
Q2 - please provide full code