# Set cascade in a bidirectional one to many mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm fairly new to hibernate and don't seem to fully understand the cascade.

So, I have the Job and the Client class and what I want to achieve is this:

1. If I delete a client the job is deleted as well
2. If I delete a job the client doesn't get deleted

My model looks something like this at the moment:

```java
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long clientId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Job> jobs;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Job {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long jobId;
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;
    // getters, setters and some fields were omitted for brevity
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cascade` you can perform [some operations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade) on entities transitively. If the state of one entity is changed, so it can change the state of an associated entity.

1. **If REMOVE Client -> REMOVE ALL associated Job**
   You can use:

   - `@OneToMany(mappedBy="client", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE) // or you could make all operations to be cascaded with CascadeType.ALL`
   - `@OneToMany(mappedBy="client", orphanRemoval = true)`
     [Differences between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329577/how-does-jpa-orphanremoval-true-differ-from-the-on-delete-cascade-dml-clause/12026781#12026781)
2. **If REMOVE Job -> DON'T REMOVE associated Client**
   You should exclude cascade type of REMOVE, enumerating explicitly those cascade types you need, or don't specify `cascade` attribute at all.